# Python: How to do an animation (x,y,z,t)?

Tags: python, animation, time, contour

I have a file of data.

First column, time
Second column, latitude
Third column, longitude
Fourth column, precipitation value
Right now, I have it so that the precipitation values are plotted onto a map as colors.
How would I do a animation, where users can type in the time range that they want?

```
061560 36.268 -80.39 15 
061560 36.732 -79.87 15 
061560 36.300 -82.46 15 
061560 35.926 -79.98 15 
061560 36.999 -80.55 15
061560 36.067 -79.29 15 
061560 35.808 -83.94 15 
061562 34.890 -85.21 45 
061560 35.840 -78.78 15 
061560 35.335 -80.64 15 
061560 36.094 -79.09 15 
061561 35.184 -80.86 15 
061561 35.921 -81.17 15 
061561 34.958 -80.77 25 
061561 35.131 -80.83 15 
061561 36.733 -79.87 15 
061561 34.732 -81.30 35
```

Comment: where do you stuck? what is your question? How to transition smoothly (visually) between two time data points?

Comment: I do not know how set the time equal to column 1 in mathplotlib.

Comment: do you understand [the animation examples from matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/index.html)?

Comment: No. Is there a way to make an animation where you can import the dimensions like time=file[:,0:1],  x=file[:,2:3],  y=file[:,1:2],   colors=file[:,3:4]

Comment: it has nothing to do with animation, see [`unpack` parameter for `numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)